# How to obtain a value in a collection based on a property

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the SMO collection of views, and would like to extract a view from this collection based on its "TABLE_NAME" property, i.e. the TABLE_NAME column in the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
```

After executing the above query, let's say I've stored the table name in a variable called `name`.

How can I return the view with that name?  I've tried the following, however it does not check for the view name, but rather the TABLE_SCHEMA + TABLE_NAME:

```
currentDatabase.Views[name];
```

For example, if I want to get a view whose name is "Testing", the collection would not return anything on calling `currentDatabase.Views["Testing"]` as the view would be stored as `[Schema].[Testing]` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem myself. If anyone has the same problem, the View collection has an overloaded option where you can specify the name and schema, like so:

```
currentDatabase.Views[name, schema];
```